# Warning during installation of Cordova in Mac

Tags: cordova, npm, ionic-framework

I get the following warning while installing Cordova via npm:

```
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"})
```

Command used:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It is a warning, not error. I don't think it is halting your installation.

Comment: What I do wrong? I took manual from here http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html

Comment: Like mudasser ajaz said: It's a warning and not an error, so there is no need to fix it. Cordova will work. But, if you want to fix it, you have to install an older version of node.

Comment: it is straight forward that your node version is greater than it wanted. But as i said i don't think your installation is getting failed. run `cordova` command, and if works then you don't have to worry about anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for help. Cordova and ionic works without errors